# How do I process a block of code with proceed results stored in variable in php?

Tags: php

I have a php app where I have snippets of code that I want to process and store in a variable. It might be the output of array data with HTML that I want stored…

```
$myVar = { // bracket represents starting the store

  foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo ‘<td>’ . $value . ‘</td>’;
  }
}// close bracket represents end store
```

Now the variable would hold the value of what that full echo output would be.

Is there a php function, process, or recommend way of doing this.

I don’t have a framework I’m using on this project.

I am looking for a solution because I don’t know the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ob_start and ob_get_clean functions to store the output of the code in a variable:

```
    ob_start();
    foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
      echo ‘<td>’ . $value . ‘</td>’;
    }
    $myVar = ob_get_clean();
```

ob_start turns on output buffering, which captures all output from your script and stores it in a buffer. The ob_get_clean function then retrieves the contents of the buffer and discards it, leaving you with the contents stored in the $myVar variable.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. I've tested it with an actual expected process which is a mix of code and html outside of php brackets.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$myVar = '<td>' . implode('</td><td>', $myArray) . '</td>';
```